# Deployed war files not showing in the wildfly console

Tags: web, wildfly

I already deployed some war files in the console. But it doesn't show any deployed items in the list and it is empty.Do any one know the reason for that?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure they deployed?

Comment: post server.log in order to see the contents